# Google map zoom controls in browser mobile view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am using google map in my react app, Zoom controls are just fine in desktop browser view, but when I go into browser mobile view, if I click the zoom control (no matter + or -) the map below these controls seems to be clicked too. e.g. When I click '-' button the map zooms out but the marker's position changes too.
The only difference in my code for desktop and mobile view is the position of zoom controls as below:

```
zoomControlOptions: {
  position: zoomButtonLocation === 'top_left' ? maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP : maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM,
},
```

I even tried not to change the position of zoom controls in mobile view but the problem persists.
Can anyone help me please on this issue? I searched but couldn't find any answer.
It's my first question here, If any more description or clarification needed I'm here.

Comment: Add event.preventDefault() on buttons to prevent event to go further on Map

Answer (score 1):

As @Dolly mentioned in the comment, If you add `event.preventDefault()` on buttons the problem would be solved.

Comment: Great Abraham, Thankx